# are predictions in a GRU unit based on candidate cell value, or the final memory cell value?

Tags: machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network, gru

I am learning about GRU's, and something doesn't make sense to me. I've attached the slide that this question is based on (this slide is taken from the "Gated Recurrent Unit (GRU)" video in Andrew Ng's Sequence Models course on Coursera)

It seems from his descriptions and from the diagram here that the softmax would take its input from c, i.e. from the updated memory cell value that is computed at this time-step.

However, that doesn't make sense to me because I think the purpose of the memory cell is to preserve values across multiple time-steps. As a simple example it might preserve the fact that the word "cat" is singular in the long sentence "The cat, which already ate, ..., ..., was full" so that the fact that it was singular could be used to help choose the word "was" at the end of the sentence.

Given that the memory cell isn't changing at every time-step, it seems like it would be bad to use it as the input for the softmax. The softmax might end up choosing the same word for many time-steps in a row, since it would always have the same input! Instead, it seems like it might be best to use the **candidate** values as input to the softmax, i.e. the "c~" values in the diagram.

Does that make sense? If we should really use c as input to the softmax, why wouldn't that represent a problem as I describe?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The memory cell definitely is changing at every time-step. It's just that the GRU also allows parts of the memory to be gated and stay more-or-less constant. In a 64-dimension cell memory value, storing the fact that the cat is singular only needs to use one of those dimensions, leaving the other 63 free to change.